# Chrome Extension: How do I get rid of the FOUC?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The essence of the problem is as follows:

There is a page, I need to modify the contents of the browser extensions, you can use jQuery.

Tried `$(document).ready()`, but then the contents are still displayed for a short period (FOUC). I can not make changes to the page styles on the server.

I'm using the kango framework to build the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a combination of CSS and JavaScript.  I had the same issue using jQueryUI on a site I'm building and found that a lot of these solutions out there would make the content unavailable to those without JavaScript.

So, here is what I did:

CSS:

```
.flash #wrapper {
     display: none;
}
```

This sets `<div id="wrapper">` to hidden only if it is a decedent of the `flash` class.  So, to keep it from being hidden from those without JavaScript I add the `flash` class to `<html>` element.  So, it can only be physically hidden if an end-user has JavaScript enabled, otherwise they'll at least have access via the unstyled content.

JavaScript:

```
$('html').addClass('flash');
$(document).ready(function() {
     /* Do all your stuff */

     /* When done show the wrapper with the content styled */
     $(#wrapper).show();
});
```

Depending on your pages time to load you might get a little flash, but it won't be a flash of unstyled content, which is rather ugly.  In my case I had a jQueryUI menu item that would flash the normal `<ul>` element first then the menuUI item, and my `<div>` elements are resized with jQuery so that each `<div>` column is equal height, but it would flash the different heights first.  This fixed it while still giving accessibility to non-JavaScript browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Using only ECMAscript, you can't reliably avoid it. You have like no shot if you wait for `DOMContentLoaded` event, because at that point the DOM is pretty much rendered and displayed (which is what you see for a short period).

Your best shot would be to modify the *CSS* as soon as possible. If the *stylesheet definition* gets loaded before the DOM gets rendered and you would have set like

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

you would not see anything. You could try like

```
<body>
    <script>
        document.body.style.display = 'none';
    </script>
    <!-- more html -->
</body>
```

if that is any viable / useable solution for you.

Comment: Just to follow this through, you would then use the `DOMContentLoaded` event to show the content again - avoiding the FOUC.